# How to solve this differential equation using ode23?

Tags: matlab, gearing

> Hello! :) What I have here is a gear system I need to simulate using
> MATLAB and Simulink.

[image]

> To do that, firstly I need to get the differential equation for this
> rotation (gear) system. I **think** I managed to do so and it is as
> follows `iT1 = J * theta2''+D * theta2'+K * theta2`
>
> , where `J = i^2 * Jn1 + Jn2 + J2` (also, i is the gear ratio; `i = theta1/theta2 = N2/N1 = Tn2 / Tn1 = T2/T1`).
>
> Now I need to solve this second-order differential equation using
> ode23 in MATLAB. The problem is, I don't know any initial conditions,
> nor do I know how to get them from this particular system e.g. `y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 1` Can I still solve this particular problem without the
> initial conditions, or do I make the initial conditions up...? In case
> anyone needs it the parameters of my problem are as follows:
>
> `N2 = 90, N1 = 36, Jn1 = 0.5 Nms^2/rad, Jn2 = 0.8 Nms^2/rad, J2 = 2 Nms^2/rad, D = 8 Nms/rad, K = 5 Nm/rad`
>
> The differential equation should look like this for `y=theta2` and
> `x=T1`
>
> ```
> y''+1.3502y'+0.8439y = 0.4219x
> ```
>
> Any help would be really appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly employ `ode23` to solve this ordinary differential equation, but it's much simpler if you recruit the state space approach via [`ss`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ss.html) and then [`lsim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.lsim.html).

The response of a linear system is always the aggregate of its forced (with a null initial state) and unforced evolutions (with $T_1=0$ and a given initial state $\mathbf{x}_0$).

The unforced evolution can be determined by means of [`initial`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/initial.html).

So, to answer your direct question, the initial conditions (read the initial state) are crucial as they establish part of the transient response of the system.

```matlab
% parameters
N2  = 90;
N1  = 36;
Jn1 = 0.5;
Jn2 = 0.8;
J2  = 2;
D   = 8;
K   = 5;
J   = (N2/N1)^2 * Jn1 + Jn2 + J2;

% define the system
sys = ss([0 1; -K/J -D/J], [0; N2/(N1*J)], [1 0], 0);

% initial state: (position, velocity) [rad; rad/s]
x0 = [0.1; 0];

% define the time span
t = linspace(0, 15, 10000)';

% define the input step
T1 = zeros(length(t), 1);
T1(t>=1) = 1;

% compute the system step response at once
theta1 = lsim(sys, T1, t, x0);

% compute the system response as aggregate of the forced and unforced
% temporal evolutions
theta2 = lsim(sys, T1, t, [0; 0]) + initial(sys, x0, t);

% plot results
figure('color', 'white');
hold on;
yyaxis left;
plot(t, T1, '-.', 'linewidth', 2);
ylabel('[N]');
yyaxis right;
plot(t, theta1, 'linewidth', 3);
plot(t, theta2, 'k--');
xlabel('t [s]');
ylabel('[rad]');
grid minor;
legend({'$T_1$', '$\theta_1$', '$\theta_2$'}, 'Interpreter', 'latex',...
       'location', 'southeast');
hold off;
```

Here's the resulting plot:

[image]

---

If you really want to use `ode23`, then you can run the following snippet:

```matlab
% initial state: (position, velocity) [rad; rad/s]
x0 = [0.1; 0];

% define the time span
t = linspace(0, 15, 10000)';

% integrate the differential equation
[t, x] = ode23(@fun, t, x0);

% plot results
figure('color', 'white');
plot(t, x(:, 1));
xlabel('t [s]');
ylabel('[rad]');
grid minor;
legend({'$\theta$'}, 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'location', 'southeast');


function g = fun(t, x)
% parameters
N2  = 90;
N1  = 36;
Jn1 = 0.5;
Jn2 = 0.8;
J2  = 2;
D   = 8;
K   = 5;
J   = (N2/N1)^2 * Jn1 + Jn2 + J2;

% compute gradient
g = zeros(2, 1);
g(1) = x(2);
g(2) = (-K/J)*x(1) + (-D/J)*x(2) + (N2/(N1*J)*(t>=1));
end
```

yielding the graph below:

[image]

---

Finally, if you aim to integrate a generic input as a function of time $t$, you could resort to the code below:

```matlab
function x = integrate(t, u, x0)
    % parameters
    N2  = 90;
    N1  = 36;
    Jn1 = 0.5;
    Jn2 = 0.8;
    J2  = 2;
    D   = 8;
    K   = 5;
    J   = (N2/N1)^2 * Jn1 + Jn2 + J2;

    % integrate the differential equation
    [t, x] = ode23(@fun, t, x0);

    % plot results
    figure('color', 'white');
    
    % plot position
    yyaxis left;
    plot(t, x(:, 1));
    ylabel('$x$ [rad]', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
    
    % plot velocity
    yyaxis right;
    plot(t, x(:, 2));
    ylabel('$\dot{x}$ [rad/s]', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
    
    grid minor;
    xlabel('$t$ [s]', 'Interpreter', 'latex');

    function g = fun(t, x)
        g = zeros(2, 1);
        g(1) = x(2);
        g(2) = (-K/J)*x(1) + (-D/J)*x(2) + (N2/(N1*J)*u(t));
    end
end
```

You can now employ [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to specify the temporal evolution of the input. For example, if the input is sinusoidal with pulse frequency $\omega = 0.5 \; \text{rad/s}$, you'll need to run:

```matlab
t = linspace(0, 15, 10000)';
x0 = [0.1; 0];
integrate(t, @(t)(sin(0.5*t)), x0);
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: I completely agree that it is much simpler to use state space model to solve this problem, but I specifically want to use "ode23". I am not sure what the problem seems to be, but when I use your snippet I get an "error in fun, g(1) = x(2);", "Not enough input arguments". I am not sure why this particular error seems to appear. Other than that, thank you for you comment. :)

Comment: I've just tried again my snippet from scratch by copying and pasting it in MATLAB and it works fine. It may be due to some old MATLAB version? I'm using the latest R2020b. Here's the ode23 relevant documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode23.html#bu5ypsv_sep_shared-odefun.

Comment: It's very much possible :)
I am using R2018a and it simply isn't working for me even when copying and pasting. I'd also like to add that instead of J2 which is used in the state-space model and the ode23 example, it should be J which is equal to -> J = [(N2/N1)^2*Jn1]+Jn2+J2  :)
Could you possibly, run your code for ode23 again and just send me the resulting graph by putting this J parameter instead of J2 which you wrote. So it should be 
`g = zeros(2, 1);
g(1) = x(2);
g(2) = (-K/J)*x(1) + (-D/J)*x(2) + (N2/(N1*J2)*(t>=1));
end`

The resulting graph should look a little bit different

Comment: Done! There's a slight overshoot indeed.

Comment: Thank you so very much!!! :)

Comment: You may consider marking my post as the answer then 

Comment: I did, thank you so much again! 
This is a really interesting topic for me which I am just getting into. I have one final question. I noticed you solved my problem to what appears as a "step" function (Heaviside), what if I wanted to solve the same problem but with a sine wave function. How would one do that? I would know how to regulate using a PID regulator, just not sure how to simulate a function for a sine wave input.

Comment: You have to simply replace the factor `(t>=1)` with `sin(w*t)` where `w` is the pulse frequency.

Comment: I am curious, shouldn't the factor `T1(t>=1)=1` really be `T1(t>=0)=1` if I wanted a Heaviside function?
Also, I realized it should be `sin(w*t)`, but I can't seem to make it work... :( 
How would I define this sine wave function for this particular problem let's say?
I am sorry if I annoy you with this, I am just an undergrad who is trying to learn all of this. :)

Comment: `(t>=1)` is simply a Heaviside translated in time to start at $t=1 \; \text{s}$. I've edited my answer to provide you with a generic function capable of integrating generic inputs. An example for sinusoidal inputs is also given. Hope this helps out.

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you so very much. :)