# How to simulate a system output with a sine wave input?

Tags: control, matlab

I wish to simulate the output of a certain gear system I have. How the gear system looks isn't particularly important to the problem, I managed to get the differential equation needed from the mechanical system. Here is the code I have (big thanks to the person who helped me with this)

```
% parameters
N2  = 90;
N1  = 36;
Jn1 = 0.5;
Jn2 = 0.8;
J2  = 2;
D   = 8;
K   = 5;
J   = (N2/N1)^2 * Jn1 + Jn2 + J2;

% define the system
sys = ss([0 1; -K/J -D/J], [0; N2/(N1*J)], [1 0], 0);

% initial state: (position, velocity) [rad; rad/s]
x0 = [0; 0];

% define the time span
t = linspace(0, 15, 10000)';

% define the input step
T1 = zeros(length(t), 1);
T1(t>=0) = 1;

% compute the system step response at once
theta1 = lsim(sys, T1, t, x0);

% compute the system response as aggregate of the forced and unforced
% temporal evolutions
theta2 = lsim(sys, T1, t, [0; 0]) + initial(sys, x0, t);

% plot results
figure('color', 'white');
hold on;
yyaxis left;
plot(t, T1, '-.', 'linewidth', 2);
ylabel('[N]');
yyaxis right;
plot(t, theta1, 'linewidth', 3);
plot(t, theta2, 'k--');
xlabel('t [s]');
ylabel('[rad]');
grid minor;
legend({'$T_1$', '$\theta_1$', '$\theta_2$'}, 'Interpreter', 'latex',...
       'location', 'southeast');
hold off;
```

This should work in generating a graph that shows the positions, my outputs, for a Heaviside/step input. My question is, how would I do this for a sine wave input. I figure I should have `sin(w*t)` instead of `(t>=0)`, where w is my pulse frequency. Still, I can't seem to make this work. Any help would be really appreciated! :)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you have tried for the sine wave? Did you use T1=sin(w*t)?

Comment: Hello there, yes I did and it didn't work, an error appears. What I suspect the problem may be are the negative values in the arrays which are generated by the sine wave.

Comment: Could you show in more detail what you tried and what errors you got in return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marx, you already asked me this and I've provided the answer to that in the bottom line of https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/21740/6941.

Let me recall the function here as well:

```matlab
function x = integrate(t, u, x0)
    % parameters
    N2  = 90;
    N1  = 36;
    Jn1 = 0.5;
    Jn2 = 0.8;
    J2  = 2;
    D   = 8;
    K   = 5;
    J   = (N2/N1)^2 * Jn1 + Jn2 + J2;

    % integrate the differential equation
    [t, x] = ode23(@fun, t, x0);

    % plot results
    figure('color', 'white');
    
    % plot position
    yyaxis left;
    plot(t, x(:, 1));
    ylabel('$x$ [rad]', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
    
    % plot velocity
    yyaxis right;
    plot(t, x(:, 2));
    ylabel('$\dot{x}$ [rad/s]', 'Interpreter', 'latex');
    
    grid minor;
    xlabel('$t$ [s]', 'Interpreter', 'latex');

    function g = fun(t, x)
        g = zeros(2, 1);
        g(1) = x(2);
        g(2) = (-K/J)*x(1) + (-D/J)*x(2) + (N2/(N1*J)*u(t));
    end
end
```

Example call:

```matlab
t = linspace(0, 15, 10000)';
x0 = [0.1; 0];
x = integrate(t, @(t)(sin(0.5*t)), x0);
```

Comment: I've just seen your answer, thank you so very much! :)

Comment: For linear time invariant systems lsim() might be more accurate than ode23() (depending on the time step size for lsim and the tolerances for ode23).

Comment: I know, but the OP specifically asked for ode23 in the other Q that I pointed at.